# C++ virtual class method

Tags: c++, class, virtual

Imagine I have a super class A in C++ that has a virtual method. If I want to override it on my class B and still keep it virtual is it recommended to keep the virtual keyword on the class B on can I ignore it because I already said that method is virtual on the super class?

For example what is the correct way to do the following.

**Method A:**

```
class A{ 
    public:
        virtual void hello(){
            std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        };
};
class B: public A{
    public:
        virtual void hello() override{
            std::cout << "Hello Sun!" << std::endl;
        };

};
class C: public B{
    public:
        virtual void hello() override{
            std::cout << "Hello Moon!" << std::endl;
        };

};
```

Or declaring the function as virtual only on the first class.

**Method B:**

```
class A{ 
    public:
        virtual void hello(){
            std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        };
};
class B: public A{
    public:
        void hello() override{
            std::cout << "Hello Sun!" << std::endl;
        };

};
class C: public B{
    public:
        void hello() override{
            std::cout << "Hello Moon!" << std::endl;
        };

};
```

I want to use late biding in all situations. So I need the hello() method to be virtual in the three classes. Both ways worked on CodeBlocks but I don´t know what is the best way or even if there is any difference between them.

Comment: You don't need to keep the `virtual` keyword. What's going wrong with your code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hey thanks for you reply. My code works fine I just did not know what was the best way to implement it (A or B). Now I know I don´t need to keep the virtual keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtual` is superfluous for `B` and `C`, and the effect is exactly the same. The important thing is to always mark your methods with `override`<sup>1</sup> if they're meant to override a virtual method. While this is not strictly necessary, it is a good practice. You're doing that correctly in both examples.

Pertinent standardese:

> n4140
>
> § 10.3 [class.virtual] / 2
>
> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in
>   a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a
>   member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list,
>   cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf`
>   is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (*whether or not it is*
>   *so declared*) and it overrides `Base::vf`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>`override` as a specifier is available since C++11.</sub>

Comment: [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier introduced in c++11, so it 's not always possible to use it.

Comment: @Nikita *looks at the calendar*. Ahem. Edited.

Comment: Tons of C++ code still using old compilers and in most situations it's not possible to upgrade.

Comment: @krzaq The usage of `override` is not required in C++11/14, although it's highly recommended so you won't make mistakes.

Comment: @vsoftco edited, is the phrasing more to your liking?

Comment: @krzaq I was referring to the footnote :)

Comment: @vsoftco oh, I can see how it could be understood both ways

Comment: @vsoftco how about now? :)